# ASP.net, c#, how to check if the value entered is numeric, it could be decimal or simply integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, double

I am trying to restrict users to enter valid decimal value (No Commas)

what is the best way.

My code :

```
try{
 Convert.ToInt32(stringToCheck)
}
catch
{
   //invlaid
}
```

It fails if the user entered a decimal value, let's say 3.0, although it's a valid value.

If I try 
`Convert.ToDouble(stringToCheck)`

this one fails to catch if the user enters 3,6

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Please show clear examples of valid and invalid values. For instance, to me, the value "1,000.0001" is a valid decimal value, but I have no idea if that's "valid" according to your rules.

Comment: Valid Values 2, 2.0 no worries about range. basically number with decimal or without decimal but no comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var stringToCheck =  "3,6";
        var isDouble =            
        double.TryParse(stringToCheck,NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
         NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out double doubleValue);

        if (isDouble)
        {
            // Do stuff if doubleValue variable
        }
        else
        {
            // code to run if not double
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression. [Here](https://www.techiedelight.com/identify-string-is-numeric-csharp/) is how.

an example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    public class Example
    {

    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "123";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+$"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given string is numeric");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Given string is non-numeric");
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the expression to accept any type of numbers.

**Update:**

The complete solution is:

```
static bool isNumeric(string s)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^-?[1-9][0-9,\.]+$"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The following code is a test:

```
Console.WriteLine(isNumeric("0123"));//returns false
Console.WriteLine(isNumeric("2.2"));//returns true
Console.WriteLine(isNumeric("-2.0"));//returns true
Console.WriteLine(isNumeric("123123.2"));//returns true
Console.WriteLine(isNumeric("123sad"));//returns false
```

Comment: this fails for decimal.

Comment: You should not reinvent the wheel with a Regex. .NET has built in methods to determine is a string is a valid integer or decimal, those should be used. You need to learn a fundamental rule about Regex: just because something *can* be done with Regex, doesn't mean it should. Regex should often be a last resort.

Comment: @learner101 that was only an example how to use regex for this problem and was not a solution. I told you at the end of post, you should extend the regex and check the manual!

Comment: @mason which built in function do you mean?

Comment: int.TryParse, decimal.TryParse, double.TryParse etc.

Comment: @mason Thank you. I think we have String.isNumeric in c#!!! :)